# What is the way of extracting values from xml document using XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm currently working on extracting data from a form. I'm able to extract the rpm-type and attributes like ccoid_key, ccoid_version but I'm unable to extract the "190".
I'm using the folowing syntax '//form/*/*/rpm-type/.' and tested it on http://www.xpathtester.com/test which seems to return want I want...

```
<form xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"     xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-    runner" xmlns:ns2="http://db.rpm" xmlns:ns3="http://wscommon.rpm"    xmlns:ns4="http://form.rpm" xmlns:ns5="http://form.rpm" xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
<section-data>
<date>2012-06-12Z</date>
<author-name>admin admin</author-name>
<note>note</note>
</section-data>
<section-2>
<control-4>
<rpm-type ccoid_key="K000001" ccoid_version="1" type="rpm-weight">
   <rpm-value ccoid_key="K000002" type="rpm-weight-kg">190</rpm-value>
</rpm-type> 
</control-4>
<control-5>
<rpm-type ccoid_key="K000001" ccoid_version="1" type="rpm-weight">
    <rpm-value ccoid_key="K000002" type="rpm-weight-lbs">222</rpm-value>
    <rpm-value ccoid_key="K000003" type="rpm-weight-oz">21</rpm-value>
</rpm-type>
</control-5>
</section-2>
</form>
```

I'm using node.getNodeValue() but I get a null...
From the logs, I can see I was able to extract many of the attributes and their values,
but when trying to get the value of the childNode, I get null :

2012-06-12 14:17:49,028 [http-thread-pool-1234(2)] DEBUG [FormSrvcImpl:944] Path :[//form/*/*/rpm-type/.]
**2012-06-12 14:17:49,039 [http-thread-pool-1234(2)] DEBUG [FormSrvcImpl:1007] node value found : null**
2012-06-12 14:17:49,040 [http-thread-pool-1234(2)] DEBUG [FormSrvcImpl:1054] Clinical Unit to add :ClinicalUnit [idCcUnit=, idCc=0, ccoidUnitKey=K000002, ccoidUnitVersion=0]
2012-06-12 14:17:49,041 [http-thread-pool-1234(2)] DEBUG [FormSrvcImpl:1055] Clinical Type to add :ClinicalType [idCcClinicalType=, idCc=0, ccoidClinicalTypeKey=rpm-weight, ccoidClinicalTypeVersion=1, valueType=null, units=null]
2012-06-12 14:17:49,041 [http-thread-pool-1234(2)] DEBUG [FormSrvcImpl:1056] Clinical Value to add :ClinicalValue [id_clinical_value=0, clinicalType=ClinicalType [idCcClinicalType=, idCc=0, ccoidClinicalTypeKey=rpm-weight, ccoidClinicalTypeVersion=1, valueType=null, units=null], clinicalValue=null, valueDate=null, status=ACTIVE, sourceType=ORBEON_FORM, idSource=18585, idPatient=219, clinicalUnit=null]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Javadoc [`getNodeValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29) return null if it's call on some kind of Nodes (see the table at the start of the previous link). You should probably use [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you're trying to use getNodeValue() on rpm-type (which has no value, only a child node) instead of the rpm-value node which has the 190 value you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I get the childNodes, iterate over them. I can get the attributes but not the value.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I found the value in the node.getTextContent...